# Jack audio connection kit + Windows audio

Tags: windows, audio, jack

I need to do the following:

get the system audio output ("What you hear" in Windows) in order to do some processing...

My thoughts were to pass the audio output to a Jack client and then to my program.

My OS is Win7 64bit and i am working in VC++ (VS2005)

Any one has any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to capture the audio from the Stereo Mix.

[See this article for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713735%28VS.85%29.aspx)